# Mover archivo cargado al servidor con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, windows

necesito poder subir un documento al servidor a traves de laravel, si ejecuto mi formulario, este me guarda los datos en la base de datos y me guarda el documento localmente, pero en el servidor no hay caso que aparezca dicho documento, pongo mi codigo

```
    if ($request->hasFile('archivo')) {
       $file = $request->file('archivo');
       $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $newName = "/personal/".$name;
       $path = public_path() .'\personal';
       $file->move($path,$name);
   }else{
       echo "Debes subir documento"
   }
```

Si imprimo mi varible `$path` me arroja lo siguiente

C:\Users\JUANJO\Desktop\Trabajos - Proyecto\public\personal

Y como digo, si apreto el botón guardar de mi formulario, este me guarda como debe ser en la base de datos y en mi carpeta local también guarda.  Pero al servidor no me sube, tampoco me arroja error.  Si me voy al servidor y veo que permiso tiene mi carpeta personal es 775, que estoy realizando mal, ayuda plis

Comment: Tienes una diagonal invertida \ al crear la variable, debería ser: `$path = public_path() .'/materiales';`

Comment: Amigo edite mi código e inverti como tu me dices la barra, me quedó asi $path = public_path() .'/personal'; pero tampoco me funciono :'(

Comment: otra opción es usar el Filesystem y **copiar** el archivo temporal a la otra ruta, no moverlo, puedes usar el componente Filesystem de Symfony llamándolo así: `$fileSystem->copy($uploadedFile->getPathname(), $targetPath);` en sistemas windows como el que estás trabajando el método move nos dio muchos dolores de  cabeza que resolvimos así, copiando y dejando que IIS recoja el temporal de cualquier modo. Referencia: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lo que entiendo estas tratando de subir un archivo a un servidor remoto.
si es que ese es tu problema sigue los siguientes pasos...

1. Entra a la ruta **config/filesystem.php** de tu proyecto y agrega las siguientes 
   lienas de codigo.

---

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver'   => 'ftp',
        'host'     => '192.168.0.210',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => '*****',
        'root' => 'Folder1/Folder2/2020',
    ],
```

2. Después entras a tu controlador y agregas lo siguiente.

---

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


$carpeta = "nombre-de-tu-carpeta";
$files = $request->file('archivo'); 
$nombre_archivo = $files->getClientOriginalName();

Storage::disk('ftp')->put($carpeta.'/'.$nombre_archivo.'/', \File::get($files));
```

**Esto funciona para almacenar un archivo en una carpeta que este en algún servidor externo.**

Espero y te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda